# How calculated the drag coefficient lift coefficient with pressure coefficient?

Tags: aerodynamics, lift, drag

I have got the Cp Plot on a wing, now  I am trying to calculate Cl and Cd. And the angle of attack is 0 degrees, the wing has been split into N Panels, and the normal vector ni for every Panel is already known, The airfoil(AQUILA) is like the picture:
[image]
If the friction can be ignored.
For Cl, I integrate Cp with x from 0 to 1;
For Cd, I integrate Cp with y from 0 to breadth of the airfoil.
I have tried several ways:

1. (CD, CL) = sum(Cp(i) * L(i)* n(i))/(reference length)

-Here L(i) is the length of the i 'th panel, Cp(i) ist the pressure of center point of the i 'th panel and n(i) is the normal vector for the i 'th panel.

2. like the below equation in the screenshots:

[image]

With these two methods, I can get the same Answer, Cl = 0.09, Cd = 0.006
But actually Cl should be 0.2~0.4.

Could someone give me some advice and explain, I haven't studied aerodynamics before, but there are a few parts about that in my paper

Comment: did you integrate the pressure on both sides?

Comment: Yes, I have integrated every panel length, from point (1,0) to (1,0). Do you think  I have lost something? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: It seems you added all pressure coefficients for all panels, multiplied by the panel's length. Now I wonder whether you forgot to normalize the result by dividing by the reference length. Your first equation indicates as much and the result of the summation is a length, not a dimensionless value. So it needs to be divided by a reference length.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have forgotten to add die reference length here, but in my calculation, I have already divided the length, to calculate Cl, the reference length ist the chord(usual 1), and for Cd, the length is breadth in the y-axis.

Comment: The reference length should be the same for both coefficients.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me! so both length should be chord? but will it  change the answer? cause the chord equal to 1. have I got the correct the understanding?

Comment: hey Peter, I have found an explanation about that, but I don't understand why. Cause I have only used source and sink in panel method, and sources and sinks don’t create any drag/lift. but do you know why?

Comment: Thank you for asking a new question. That was the right thing to do. Now it should be clear where the error is: Sources and sinks only simulate an obstruction but cannot generate lift. Please read @JZYL's answer – I couldn't explain it any better.

Comment: thank you anyways!